# Given a prime number p, $p \nmid a$, prove for any positive integer k, $p^k|a^{(p-1)p^{k-1}}-1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Given a prime number p, $p \nmid a$, prove for any positive integer k, $p^k|a^{(p-1)p^{k-1}}-1$

Maybe consider using this theorem:  for prime number p, if $(a,p) = 1$, then $p|a^{p-1}-1$

Comment: This is [Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem):  $a^{\phi(n)}\equiv1\pmod n$ with $n=p^k\,$ [so $\phi(n)=p^{k-1}(p-1)$]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint  : Show that $a \equiv b \pmod n \implies a^n \equiv b^n \pmod {n^2}$ and then use induction. And you already know by fermat's little theorem that $a^{p-1}\equiv 1 \pmod p$.

Proof of the hint given : $a^n-b^n=(a-b)(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}b + \cdots +b^{n-2}a+b^{n-1})$. You know $n \mid a-b$, and also,$a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}b + \cdots +b^{n-2}a+b^{n-1} \equiv na^{n-1}$ as $a\equiv b \pmod n$ and thus, $n^2 \mid a^n-b^n$.

So, you have $a^{p(p-1)}=1\pmod {p^2}$, $a^{p^2(p-1)}=1\pmod{p^3}$,... and now use induction to gt your conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

By Euler's thereom, if $\gcd(a, n) =1$ then $a^{\phi(n)} \equiv 1 \pmod n$ or in other words $n|a^{\phi(n)}-1$.

And as $p$ is prime and $p\not \mid a$ we know $\gcd(a, p^k) = 1$.

And $\phi(p^k) = (p-1)p^{k-1}$.

And that's it.  There's nothing to prove.  $p^k|a^{\phi(p^k)}-1=a^{(p-1)p^{k-1}} -1$.